# Boundary of complex numbers - confused by the interval notation

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

If $X = \mathbb{C}$, find $\partial [0,1)$.

The problem is that I have never dealt with complex numbers topology before, so I am not sure what it means. Does $[0,1)$ mean only real part $[0,1)$, where imaginary part is zero or it means something like $[0,1) \times [0,1)$?

In the first case, it seems that $\partial [0,1) = \{0,1\}$, the same as in the case when $X = \mathbb{R}$. In the second case I think the boundary in a contour of a square in the plane: $\partial [0,1) = \{[0,1] \times \{0\}\}\cup\{\{1\} \times [0,1]\}\cup\{[0,1] \times \{1\}\}\cup\{\{0\} \times [0,1]\}$.

EDIT:

Let $A = \{x + 0i: x \in [0,1)\}$. Then $\partial A = \bar A - A^o$. Since $\bar A = [0,1] + 0i$ and $A^o = \emptyset$, $\partial A = [0,1]$. Is this correct?

Comment: $[0,1)$ presumably means $\{ x + 0i | x \in [0,1) \}$. In which case we have $\partial [0,1) = [0,1]$. The boundary is the closure intersected with the closure of the complement.

Comment: Have you dealt with the $\mathbb{R}^2$ topology? It is the same as the $\mathbb{C}$ topology.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that we can view $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R^2}$. Is my edit above correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $A = \{x + 0i: x \in [0,1)\}$. Then $\partial A = \bar A - A^o$. Since $\bar A = [0,1] + 0i$ and $A^o = \emptyset$, $\partial A = [0,1]$. Is this correct?

Yes.